# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have 3 models..

A user model with ethnicity_id, and education_id associations

A education model with user_id association

A ethnicity model with user_id association

Now how it works is for example users may add education by selecting a drop down of various educations that have been migrated as seed data with the education migration. So if a user chooses bachelors for example, that becomes that users education.name as seen below:

```
  <span class="select_for_education">
        <%= best_in_place current_user, :education_id, :type => :select, collection: Education.all.map{|e| [e.id, e.name]}, :inner_class => 'education-edit', nil: 'Select Education' %>
        </div>
```

Now users can select an education np, and it saves to their personal profile but when displaying the education.name of the user I get the following error:

**Error message:**

```
 undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass


       <div class="element">
         Ethinicity:
         <%= @user.ethnicity.name.present? ? @user.ethnicity.name : "" %>
       </div>
```

Please see the models below

**ethnicity.rb**

```
class Ethnicity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many_and_belongs_to_many :users

end
```

**education.rb**

```
class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many_and_belongs_to_many :users


end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable,
         :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter, :linkedin]

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :zip, :gender, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name,
                  :birthday, :current_password, :occupation, :address, :interests, :aboutme, :profile_image,
                  :photos_attributes, :age, :education_id, :ethnicity_id, :blurb

  has_many :authorizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments
  has_many :events
  has_many :photos, as: :attachable
  has_many :questions
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :sender_id
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :receiver_id
  has_one  :ethnicity
  has_one  :education
end
```

And here is how I am currently trying to display a users education to other users in the show page.

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="element">
          Ethinicity:
          <%= @user.ethnicity.name.present? ? @user.ethnicity.name : "" %>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
          Education:
          <span class="select_for_education">
           <%= @user.education.name.present? ? @user.education.name : "" %>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all cases, replace

`@user.ethnicity.name.present?` with `@user.ethnicity.present?`

and `@user.education.name.present?` with `@user.education.present?`.

---

On a separate note, `has_and_belongs_to_many` is a symmetric relationship. That is, if Ethnicity has_and_belongs_to_many Users, then User has_and_belongs_to_many Ethnicities. I don't think this is the case. Instead, I think you probably want

```
class Ethnicity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :users
end
```

and

```
class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :users
end
```

This is not the cause of the error in your question, but thought this might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that Matt - but the education isn't displaying still? Now it just displayed the following - Education: (and blank, when I know that education is infact saving to the users own profile just not displaying to others)

Comment: You haven't shown any code where you are associating a User with Ethnicity, so I'm afraid I can't help you with that. Now that this error is fixed, you can ask a new question which includes your data.

Comment: The user model was also provided above in the initial post including the ethnicity association.

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me. How are User and Ethnicity data inserted into the database, and how are they retrieved? This code is typically in the controllers. This is what we need to see, and is appropriately another question, since the issue in the current title "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass 3 models" has been solved.

Comment: Fair enough, I currently don't have any controllers for education or ethnicity as those aren't necessary. Perhaps you would be able to tell me a line of code to add to user controller show action to display the user.education.name ? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It depends on what is in your Users controller code. Post that in the new question.

Comment: Sure, here is the new question thanks so much Matt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714196/user-education-and-ethnicity-not-showing-on-usersshow-page