# Attributes not showing on users#show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**users_controller.rb**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) || User.find(current_user.id)
    @questions_for_about = @user.questions.for_about.order('id asc')
    @questions_for_personality = @user.questions.for_personality.order('id asc')
  end
end
```

**user#show.html.erb**

```
   <div class="element">
          Ethinicity:
          <%= @user.ethnicity.present? ? @user.ethnicity.name : "" %>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
          Education:
          <span class="select_for_education">
           <%= @user.education.present? ? @user.education.name : "" %>
        </div>
```

The user.education.name is just showing the following - Education:

Without showing the users Education in which was chosen on his personal profile using the following select:

```
  <div class="element">
          Ethinicity:
          <%= best_in_place current_user, :ethnicity_id, :type => :select, collection: Ethnicity.all.map{|e| [e.id, e.name]}, :inner_class => 'education-edit', nil: 'Select Ethnicity' %>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
          Education:
          <span class="select_for_education">
        <%= best_in_place current_user, :education_id, :type => :select, collection: Education.all.map{|e| [e.id, e.name]}, :inner_class => 'education-edit', nil: 'Select Education' %>
        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I get the users education that DOES display on his/her own profile to display in the show page?

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable,
         :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter, :linkedin]

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :zip, :gender, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name,
                  :birthday, :current_password, :occupation, :address, :interests, :aboutme, :profile_image,
                  :photos_attributes, :age, :education_id, :ethnicity_id, :blurb

  has_many :authorizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments
  has_many :events
  has_many :photos, as: :attachable
  has_many :questions
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :sender_id
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :receiver_id
  has_one  :ethnicity
  has_one  :education
end
```

**ethnicity.rb**

```
class Ethinicity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :users
end
```

**education.rb**

```
class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :users
end
```

Comment: How are `user`, `ethnicity` and `education` associated?  Can you post your models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `belongs_to` association for `has_many` and `has_one` relation.  The `belongs_to` association definition needs to be defined in the model whose table has the foreign key.

Given your models, although the other way around is imaginable, here is what I think the associations should look like:

```
# User Model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to  :ethnicity
  belongs_to  :education
end

# Ethnicity Model
class Ethinicity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :users
end

# Education Model
class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :users
end
```